# Laravel: guardar array en una tabla relacionada

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relaciones

Tengo la tabla Personas relacionada con la tabla Imágenes:

```
class Persona extends Model
{
    public function imagenes() {
        return $this->HasMany(Imagenes::class);
    }
}
```

He creado un form que me permite subir múltiples imágenes de una sola pasada. Las imagénes ya se guardan perfectamente en Storage.

El asunto es este: luego de que las imágenes se cargan, sus respectivos nombres se guardan en un `array` llamado `$imagenes_nombres` que luego cargo en `$request->all()`, y cuando voy a guardar...

```
if ($imagenes_nombres = Imagenes::guardarGaleria($request->imagenes_cargadas)) {
    $request->request->add(['imagenes_nombres' => $imagenes_nombres]);
}

$persona->imagenes()->save($request->imagenes_nombres);
```

Obtengo un

> *Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given*.

Usando

```
$persona->imagenes()->saveMany($request->imagenes_nombres);
```

Obtengo un

> *Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, string given*.

Tengo un problema con la relación? Qué otro tipo de instancia Eloquent me funcionaría, si no es array? Gracias.

(También he usado `sync->()` pero tampoco funciona)

Comment: ¿Qué devuelve `Imagenes::guardarGaleria()`?

Comment: Usa `create` en lugar de save. Eso crea el modelo con los argumentos dados y lo guarda automáticamente. También en el Model relacionado tienen que estar las claves que pasas en el array a create, en la variable `protected $fillable = ['clave1', 'clave2', ...]`

Comment: Jonathan, ese método guarda las imágenes en Storage, y devulve un array con los nombres respectivos para guardarlos en la base de datos.

Comment: Sería útil que muestres el Model de imágenes y el array que te devuelve el método que ya te preguntó Jonathan☺

Comment: El error es el mismo en ambos casos, le estas pasando un array de strings. Pero el método save() espera como parámetro una instancia de Model, y el método saveMany() espera como parámetro un array de instancias de Model

Comment: Requerimos para ayudarte, que nos muestres el modelo de `Imagenes` y  que te devuelve el array, no que lo describas como supones que es, porque ese podría ser el error, el ejemplo no es completo y verificable: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example